# Merging/updating XML using XSLT 1.0 with certain conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, conditional-statements

#### Good day, so I have this sample xml file that gets passed to the xslt:( actual xml I'll be using is much longer)

```
<RecordMerge>
   <ExistingRecord>      
      <Record>
         <RecordNumber>990000010</RecordNumber>
         <Name>Michel Duchovskiy</Name>
         <Gender />
         <Address>
            <Street>555 Ocean Blvd</Street>
            <City>Atlantic City</City>
            <Zip>23345</Zip>
         </Address>
      </Record>
   </ExistingRecord>

   <NewRecord>
      <Record>
         <RecordNumber>990000010</RecordNumber>
         <Name>Mick Dick</Name>
         <Gender>Male</Gender>
         <MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>
         <Address>
            <Street>123 Sunset Blvd</Street>
            <City>Beverly Hills</City>
            <Zip>90210</Zip>
         </Address>
      </Record>
   </NewRecord>

</RecordMerge>
```

So the task is, ExistingRecord/Record contents needs to be updated with NewRecord/Record contents. Forgot to mention that it doesn't need to be matched based on RecordNumber. Matching is done beforehand, and XML that is passed to this xslt will always have the same structure. RecordMerge root will always have two children, so matching is never needed.

**The conditions for merge:**

**-When the element has no children (such as Gender, Name):**

- If the element is blank inside the Existing- update the value
- If the  element is new and not inside the Existing- add to the result

**-When the element has children(such us if it's a list like Address):**

- Update the contents

Otherwise, the elements inside the ExistingRecord/Record should remain unchanged.

The result should look like this:

```
    <Record>
         <Name>Michel Duchovskiy</Name>
         <Gender>Male</Gender>
         <MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>
         <Address>
            <Street>123 Sunset Blvd</Street>
            <City>Beverly Hills</City>
            <Zip>90210</Zip>
         </Address>
      </Record>
```

As you can see, name stays unchanged, Gender value was added (since it was empty) and the address was updated. This was just an example, since xml contains hundreds of different lists and elements.

Not sure how to do it, since it is much more complicated that a simple merge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First up, I would start with the XSLT identity template to handle elements you don't need to change

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means to alter the **ExistingRecord** you would have a template to match the fields of its **Record** elements

```
<xsl:template match="ExistingRecord/Record/*">
```

In this you could declare a variable to reference the corresponding **NewRecord**'s field, assuming there was only one other in **RecordMerge**

```
<xsl:variable name="new" 
     select="../../../NewRecord/Record/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
```

Then you could you use an **xsl:choose** statement to check whether to use the **NewRecord** or the **ExistingRecord** field using the logic you have declared

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$new and *"><xsl:apply-templates select="$new" /></xsl:when>    
   <xsl:when test="$new and not(normalize-space())"><xsl:apply-templates select="$new" /></xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="identity" /></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

So, the first condition checks if the existing element has children, the second condition checks whether the existing element is empty.

This only leaves adding nodes to the **ExistingRecord** that are not currently present. To do this, you could define a key to look up the child elements present by the **RecordMerge** id and element name (I am assuming you can have multiple **RecordMerge** elements in your XML)

```
<xsl:key name="existing" 
         match="ExistingRecord/Record/*" 
         use="concat(generate-id(../../..), '|', local-name())" />
```

Then, to copy elements from the **NewRecord** to the **ExistingRecord** where they don't exist in the **ExistingRecord**, the statement would look something like this

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../../NewRecord/Record/*[not(key('existing', concat($RecordMerge, '|', local-name())))]" />
```

(Where **$RecordMerge** contains the generate-id of the current **RecordMerge** element)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="existing" match="ExistingRecord/Record/*" use="concat(generate-id(../../..), '|', local-name())" />

  <xsl:template match="ExistingRecord">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Record" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NewRecord" />

  <xsl:template match="ExistingRecord/Record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:variable name="RecordMerge" select="generate-id(../..)" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../NewRecord/Record/*[not(key('existing', concat($RecordMerge, '|', local-name())))]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ExistingRecord/Record/*">
    <xsl:variable name="new" select="../../../NewRecord/Record/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$new and *"><xsl:apply-templates select="$new" /></xsl:when>    
       <xsl:when test="$new and not(normalize-space())"><xsl:apply-templates select="$new" /></xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise><xsl:call-template name="identity" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is worth stating that this solution will add the new child elements after the existing ones, and not in the middle as your have shown in your expected output. (Because I couldn't work out how to do this.....)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, really appreciate it. I tried it, and it works!

Comment: However, I forgot to mention that it doesn't need to be matched based on RecordNumber. Matching is done beforehand, and XML that is passed to this xslt will always have the same structure. RecordMerge root will always have two children, so matching is never needed. I'll try to simplify it but if you could show me the solution without the RecordNumber matching, I'll be forever grateful!

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it no longer matches on RecordNumber.